# Is there a way to connect to Phantom wallet while web scraping with JavaScript and Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, solana, phantom-wallet

When working with interactive window, is there a way to connect to crypto wallet like Phantom (Solana blockchain is needed)? I tried to find a button, click "connect wallet", but the chrome extension does not pop-up in an interactive window as it does in a normal browser.

Comment: https://docs.phantom.app/

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you already have puppeteer loading the Chrome extension, but if you have not. You will want to add the arguments in like this:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
  headless: false,
  devtools,
  args: [
    '--disable-extensions-except=./replacer-chrome-extension',
    '--load-extension=./replacer-chrome-extension',
  ],
  ...(slowMo && { slowMo }),
});
```

Step 2:
Find the extension ID. You had the right idea to try to find look up the element, but the extension is a different DOM tree, so we want to load the extension into a new tab, by referencing the `chrome-extension://`  namespace to access those resources.

```
const extensionTarget = targets.find(target => target.type() === 'service_worker');
const partialExtensionUrl = extensionTarget._targetInfo.url || '';
const [, , extensionID] = partialExtensionUrl.split('/');
```

---

**How to retrieve the extension id for a Manifest V2 Extension?**
How to retrieve the extension id for a Manifest V2 extension?
const PAGE_TITLE = 'Text Replacer Extension';
const targets = await browser.targets();
extensionTarget = targets.find(({ _targetInfo }) => _targetInfo.title === PAGE_TITLE);
const partialExtensionUrl = extensionTarget._targetInfo.url || '';

---

Once we figure out the id, we load the extension in a tab, and similarly to the application, we grab a page reference and return it.

```
const extPage = await browser.newPage();
const extensionUrl = `chrome-extension://${extensionId}/popup.html`;
await extPage.goto(extensionUrl, { waitUntil: 'load' });

return {
  appPage,
  browser,
  extensionUrl,
  extPage,
};
```

Source: https://tweak-extension.com/blog/complete-guide-test-chrome-extension-puppeteer/